# It is possible to login with fingerprint or face ID in ionic3?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to store users fingerprints and face ID in a server side using IONIC3 ?

I want to get scan user fingerprint or face ID and save it to server side, user will scan fingerprint or face ID from login page if user matched then it will login to the system directly.

Comment: Not on iOS (and I suspect not on Android either).  On iOS the biometric data is stored securely in the device.  You can use local authentication on the device to verify the finger or face and unlock credentials (eg username/password) that have previously been stored on the device to send to your server for authentication

Comment: ok, i think local authentication will be better. Thanks! :)